# How to assign a result of an operation to Layer.kernel?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have this simple model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants

input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

l = tf.keras.layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  l.Conv2D(32, 5, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
])
```

Literally, a single convolution. Now I want to assign a result of different op to `model.layers[0].kernel`, i.e. I want the `kernel` to be formed in a special way during training and depend on another trainable parameter.

*Why would I want that? I'm experimenting with weight clustering and weights are supposed to be looked up from a trainable array. Lookup would happen with gather op.*

For now, I do a simple thing:

```
multiplier = tf.placeholder(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
model.layers[0].kernel = tf.assign(model.layers[0].kernel, multiplier * model.layers[0].kernel)
```

I would hope that this will create another op in the graph that the convolutional kernel would depend on. However, after running this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants
def freeze_session(session, keep_var_names=None, output_names=None, clear_devices=True):
  graph = session.graph
  with graph.as_default():
    freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.all_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
    output_names = output_names or []
    output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.all_variables()]
    # Graph -> GraphDef ProtoBuf
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
    if clear_devices:
      for node in input_graph_def.node:
        node.device = ""
    frozen_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(session, input_graph_def,
                                                  output_names, freeze_var_names)
    return frozen_graph
frozen_graph = freeze_session(tf.keras.backend.get_session(),
                              output_names=[out.op.name for out in model.outputs])
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, "model", "tf_model.pb", as_text=False)
```

I get this picture:

[image]

The kernel does not appear to be dependant on the placeholder I've created. 
However, if I stop in a debugger and do:

```
>>>model.layers[0].kernel
```

I get this:

```
<tf.Variable 'AssignVariableOp' shape=(5, 5, 1, 32) dtype=float32>
```

So the assignment clearly happens in the computational graph. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keras is not meant to use "placeholders" like that. It should use `Input` to create placeholders automatically and use them correctly in the model. The placeholder you created externally is certainly not considered a part of the "Keras" model (it's not performed in a Keras layer, it's not a Keras input).

So, you should have two Keras inputs:

```
data_input = Input((28,28,1))
kernel_input = Input(tensor = your_placeholder)
```

I used `tensor=` in the `Input` because it has a different batch size, and Keras usually complains about inputs that don't follow the same batch size of the others.

Now this tensor should be part of the Keras model and appear in the graph. Notice that because it's a placeholder, it will not work with `model.fit`, you will need Tensorflow training where you feed this placeholder yourself. (You may use a variable that you update instead of a placeholder too).

Now about the Kernel. You will probably need to create a custom layer. That because `kernel` will only exist after you `build` the layer, and the layer will only be built when you call it on a tensor. That means, all the layer's ops will probably be already created by the point you are trying to change the Kernel, so it will probably not take effect, or take effect only on the next batch.

So, the suggestion is:

```
class MultConv2D(Conv2D):
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MultConv2D, self).build(input_shape)
        self.kernel = kernel * multiplier
```

The troublesome part is where to input the multiplier, maybe in `__init__`, maybe in `call` (but rewriting the call method is way more complicated and will only support that the layer be called once)